# Spring Batch - Master failover in remote chunking

Tags: spring-batch

I want to scale my batch processing via Remote Chunking mechanism, which I have master for reader, and slaves for processor and writer.

If one of my slave fail, it should be ok since I have another slave. But when the master it self fail, how do I recover? Is there any mechanism to select new master?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is not.  You'd have to restart the job.